# Mysql query parameter issue in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

Got a little problem in my code, the query works fine if I manually put values in. But failed if I use my variable. The code shows below

```
my $get_meter_id = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from t_readings where meter_serial = '21001652' AND ...");
$get_meter_id->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: ".$get_meter_id->errstr;
my $meter_reg_id = $get_meter_id->fetchrow_array();
```

Above one works

```
where meter_serial = 21001652 AND ...")
```

Above one works.

```
where meter_serial = '".$variable."' AND ...")
```

Above doesn't work

```
where meter_serial = ".$variable." AND ...")
```

Above doesn't work

Many thanks.

Comment: Definately, I set $variable = 21001652;

Comment: prove it to yourself; `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper($variable)`

Comment: perhaps you could say what "failed" means?  didn't select anything?  gave an error?  what error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use placeholders. Don't fiddle about with string concatenation.

```
my $get_meter_id = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from t_readings where meter_serial=? AND ...");
my $foo = 21001652;
$get_meter_id->execute($foo) or die "Couldn't execute statement: ".$get_meter_id->errstr;
```

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
my $get_meter_id = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from t_readings where" .
     "meter_serial = ? AND ...");
$get_meter_id->execute($variable) or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . 
     $get_meter_id->errstr;
my $meter_reg_id = $get_meter_id->fetchrow_array();
```

further [reading](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/10/09/refactoring.html)